# Create a cone with shadows

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to create a *circle* with a special *shadow* effect.
Like this one:

[image: Circle with shadow].

It should look like a cone in wood or metal.

I tried to do something with the radial gradiant in canvas but i can't creat that special Effekt.
I don´t know how to create the this shadow effect.

Can somebody give me a tip or help me?

This is what I've tried: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtbqLe5r/1/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 100,
y = 75,
innerRadius = 1,
outerRadius = 70,
radius = 60;

ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, innerRadius, x, y, outerRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF9900');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FFFFFF');

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

Greetings from Germany
Matzuman

Comment: You may want to replace `#FFFFFF` with `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`. A gradient to `0` alpha looks a lot better than a gradient to white.

Comment: okay thanks, but the important thing is the shadow effect. That there is a Little bit a dark yellow and a Little bit a lighter yellow. Sorry it is hard for me to explain it in englisch :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no gradient type in canvas which allow you to specify a radiant gradient. You have to provide a mechanism to do so manually.

You *could* use a shadow approach drawing the object off-screen while offsetting the shadow so it overlapped the cone base. One for light and one for dark side.

You can achieve a better effect though by drawing a "light/dark stripe" rotated around the center at varying opacity levels depending on angle.

[image: snap]

## Example "rendering" the cone

This example allow you to adjust parameters like how visible the reflections should be, what colors, size of cone etc. Experiment with the values to find what you're after.

To offset the "light source", just rotate one time initially with the angle you need before rendering the overlapping stripes.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    cx = 75, cy = 75, radius = 70,     // for arc/cone
    maxOpacity = 1,                    // max opacity (will accumulate)
    angleStep = 0.01,                  // "resolution"
    angle = 0, t;                      // current angle and opacity

// draw base of cone
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(139, 108, 33)";
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

// now rotate around center drawing a white stripe at varying opacity
// depending on angle
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(181, 159, 109)";
ctx.translate(cx, cy);                 // pivot for rotation = center of cone

// half of the cone is done with white overlay
for(angle = 0; angle < Math.PI; angle += angleStep) {
  // calculate t [0,1] based on angle. Multiply with max opacity
  t = (angle < Math.PI * 0.5 ? angle : Math.PI - angle) / Math.PI * maxOpacity;
  ctx.rotate(angleStep);               // increase angle by step
  ctx.globalAlpha = t;                 // set opacity to t
  drawStripe();                        // draw a small segment / "stripe"
}

// the other half of the cone is done with dark overlay
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(95, 54, 5)";
for(angle = 0; angle < Math.PI; angle += angleStep) {
  t = (angle < Math.PI * 0.5 ? angle : Math.PI - angle) / Math.PI * maxOpacity;;
  ctx.rotate(angleStep);
  ctx.globalAlpha = t;
  drawStripe();
}

function drawStripe() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, angleStep*5);
  ctx.fill();
}

// top off by drawing a smaller circle on top
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);          // reset transforms
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;                    // reset alpha
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(130, 97, 32)";     // draw in a topping
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius * 0.25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Example approximating a cone shape with shadows

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    cx = 75, cy = 75, radius = 70, offset = radius * 2;

// draw base of cone
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(139, 108, 33)";
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

// offset next shape, couter-offset its shadow
ctx.translate(cx, offset*2);                    // make sure shape is drawn outside
ctx.scale(0.75, 1);                             // make shadow more narrow
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";   // comp. on top of existing pixels

ctx.shadowOffsetY = -offset * 1.1;              // counter-offset shadow
ctx.shadowBlur = 25;                            // some blur
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(181, 159, 109, 1)";   // highlight color

ctx.beginPath();                                // draw new shape
ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.6, 0, 2*Math.PI);      // reduce radius ~50%
ctx.fill();

ctx.shadowOffsetY = -offset * 1.8;              // counter-offset shadow
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(95, 54, 5, 0.7)";       // shadow
ctx.beginPath();                                // draw new shape
ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.6, 0, 2*Math.PI);      // reduce radius ~50%
ctx.fill();

// top off by drawing a smaller circle on top
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);                  // reset transforms
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";   // reset comp. mode
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(130, 97, 32)";             // draw in a topping
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius * 0.25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow man, the first example Looks great. I hope i can integrate it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
ctx.shadowColor = "#FF9900";
```

before drawing the circle.
`shadowBlur` sets the size of the shadow, you can set it to 0 if you want to disable it.
`shadowColor` is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: i tried to do what you said, but i can´t create that effect. The Shadow goes out of the circle and the circle have the normal Color :-(

Comment: You could try to make a really tiny circle with a very large shadow.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  but it doesn´t work. May i´m to stuid :-P.  Do you have an example for me?

Comment: Well this is awkward, I tried to recreate the circle using my previously mentioned method but it doesn't seem to work.
I don't think `shadowBlur` works with arc's.

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for trying. Maybe someone have an other solution for me.